# C++: ¿Qué pasa si no utilizo el operador delete[]?

Tags: c++

Hola recientemente he aprendido como crear arrays dinámicos utilizando punteros y mi pregunta sería ¿Qué pasa si antes de finalizar el programa no uso el operador `delete[]` ? puesto que lo intente y no me apareció ningún error al compilar ni nada.

Comment: Se queda ocupado el espacio de memoria.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Imagina que compras un pack de yogures<sup>1</sup>:

---

[image]

---

No, mejor imagina que compras cien packs de yogures y en un apoteósico antojo de productos derivados de la leche te los comes todos en un día. ¿Qué pasa si dejas los envases en la basura de tu casa y no los llevas al contenedor?

---

[image]

---

No pasa nada ¿Verdad? Tu casa sigue cumpliendo su función y nadie tiene por qué quejarse de lo que haces en tu propia casa. Así que al día siguiente repites la operación, y al siguiente, y al otro.

Al cabo de siete días tienes 4200 envases de yogures vacíos en tu cocina, tienes que hacer virguerías cada vez que quieres abrir la nevera, pero por lo demás el resto de la casa funciona a la perfección.

Al cabo de un mes tienes 168000 envases de yogures vacíos en tu casa, te es difícil moverte con libertad por las habitaciones llenas de envases de yogur, pero ¡hey! no pasa nada.

No pasa nada hasta que un día unos amables señores con bata se acercan a ti con una camisa mágica que es un poco incómoda para mover los brazos; por algún motivo insisten en llamarte [Diógenes](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%C3%ADndrome_de_Di%C3%B3genes) pero no le das importancia porque te han dicho que todo irá bien.

---

Este relato explica lo que pasa cuando en tus programas no borras la memoria que solicitas, ya sea con `delete` o con `delete[]`; parece que no pasa nada pero si insistes en no tirar la basura, al final la basura se te comerá.

---

<sup>1</sup>Esta publicación no ha sido patrocinada por ninguna marca.

Comment: Muy gráfico :-)

Comment: +1 Por tan buena explicación xD Sería usted un buen maestro para pequeños programadores

Answer (score 5):

> ¿Que pasa si antes de finalizar el programa no uso el operador delete[] ?

Pues pueden pasar muchas cosas o no pasar absolutamente nada.

Hay básicamente dos aspectos a tener en cuenta:

- Memoria asociada al objejo
- Recursos bloqueados por el objeto

**Memoria**

Por defecto, los programas son estancos en cuanto a memoria se refiere, es decir, cuando un programa finaliza, el Sistema Operativo libera toda la memoria asociada al mismo.

Sin embargo, esto no va a suceder durante la ejecución de dicho programa... si no liberas la memoria y el programa vive el tiempo suficiente, el equipo se quedará sin memoria y tu programa no será capaz de seguir funcionando.

**Recursos**

Imagínate ahora que uno de tus objetos abre una conexión de red y abre una serie de archivos en un servidor... al abrir estos archivos (de ahora en adelante recursos), los has bloqueado y nadie más puede usarlos... si no liberas esos recursos (en este caso, cerrar los archivos), los mismos se quedarán bloqueados por tiempo indefinido...

de hecho podrías probar a cerrar el programa, abrirlo de nuevo y ver que entonces no puedes abrir los archivos porque están bloqueados...

Esta responsabilidad en la gestión de recursos suele recaer en los destructores de los objetos... si tu no liberas la memoria usando `delete`, estos destructores no se van a invocar y, en consecuencia, los recursos que esté bloqueando tu programa no se van a liberar.

Y por recursos podemos entender cualquier servicio o entidad externa a la que acceda tu programa:

- Archivos
- Impresoras
- Discos
- Servicios web
- ...

**Resumen**

Liberar los objetos que no necesitamos es necesario.

Aunque nuestro programa actual no requiera explícitamente que liberemos esa memoria, llegará un momento en el que este requisito pase a ser imprescindible... si no hemos adquirido buenas costumbres al respecto, nos veremos en una situación bastante dolorosa que nos va a dar unos cuantos dolores de cabeza hasta dar con la solución.

Por otro lado, acumular basura en nuestro programa no va a contribuir en nada a su correcto funcionamiento, de la misma manera que dejar un regero de recursos bloqueados en la red tampoco te va a ayudar a convertirte en empleado del mes.

Answer (score 0):

La memoria no es retornada al sistema y en consecuencia se van acumulando y pueden paralizar o incluso bloquear un programa si no se controlan. Es lo que se conoce como **memory leaks** o pérdida de memoria. Todo programa debe evitar que se produzcan  estás fugas  de memoria porque degradan a todo  a todo el sistema.